# Interrupting the onMeasure cycle to display an error (Android)

Tags: android, view, overriding, onmeasure

I've overriden the `getView(int, View, ViewGroup)` method of View to provide some custom behaviour and I'd like to be able to abort the recursive `measure() -> onMeasure() -> measureChildStuff() -> child.measure()` if an error occurrs during my custom `getView()` call, and immediately stop trying to render that Activity in favour of another that shows the error.

Unfortunately, it seems Android insists on finishing the stack of measuring before listening to my Intent to change the Activity. Is there a way I can force an Intent to be immediately started? For example, could I achieve anything by overriding `Context.startActivity()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set visibility to View.GONE, layout will skip that view.